# VBA For loop only show the last data

Tags: vba, for-loop

```
Dim l As Integer
Dim last As Integer

last = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count 

Range("AE1").Select
Selection.Value = "Open RPR $"

For l = 2 To last
    Range("AE" & l).Formula = "=$U$" & l & "*$AC$" & l
Next l
ActiveCell.Clear
```

I am trying to multiply whole column of 'U' & 'AC' and display them at 'AE'. But, the output only show the last result of multiplication for all 'AE' column.

- e.g.
  145.49
  145.49
  145.49
  ...

Can anyone tell me what's wrong in this code?

Comment: what value are you getting for your `last` ? you could replace your `For` loop, and just use `Range("AE2:AE" & last).Formula = "=$U2" & "*$AC2"` to enter the formula in the entire range at once

Comment: Is the above your complete code? I ran your code and it works fine.

Comment: @ShaiRado I get the last rows digit for `last` that is 826. Your code works fine for me but can I know why the for loop can't work ?

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn it woks fine but not the result I want. Are you getting all same output for the entire 'AE' column ?

Comment: I placed 1 thru 10 in column U & AC rows 1-10 and save the result in col AE.  Is your intent to multiply one row and save in same row, or do you want to multiply multiple rows at one time? Please explain. What rows are your 145.49 in? Each row?

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn I want the multiplication of U & AC to be displayed at column AE.

Comment: Your code (with my test data), for row 2, which has "2" in the two columns, results in "4" being stored in cell AE2; row 3 results in "9", etc.

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn Strange. My data is a pivot table though. Does it affect anything?

Comment: Yes, I tested with a pivot table. I suggest you use @Shai's solution since that worked for you.

Comment: Your code will fail with `Overflow` error when `ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count > 32767`. Declare your variables as `Long`, and use meaningful names `l` is too visually similar to `1` and doesn't have any meaning to your future self or replacement.